# ¿Por qué AppComponent no se puede usar como componente de entrada?

Tags: angularjs

Estoy tratando de comenzar con Angular pero realmente tengo problemas para lanzar ng serve --open pero encontro problemas :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Documents/Coursera/Angular/conFusion3$ ng serve --open
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 10% building modules 7/12 modules 5 active .../webpack/hot nonrecursive /^\.\/log$/webpack: wait until bundle finished: /
Date: 2018-04-25T11:58:22.910Z                                                       
Hash: ca27691c54acab3a1590
Time: 2973ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 2.91 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 577 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 42.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 852 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in AppComponent cannot be used as an entry component.

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Pienso que el problema proviene de `app.component.ts`, no sé si podemos encontrar un lugar donde esté marcado app.component.ts en algún otro lugar del proyecto ...

Pueden  encontrar mi código [sobre Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/AntoineCompagnie/confusion).

Yo uso las siguientes versiones:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 9.2.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo en el código que tienes en BitBucket tienes varios errores.

Primero app.component.ts tendría que tener un código similar:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <h1> Hola Mundo </h1>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "Prueba";
}
```

Pero lo que tienes en app.component.ts es lo que tendrías que tener en app.module.ts de ahi que te marque el error.

Luego he visto el contenido de app.component.ts entiendo que no has subido todo el código, ya que no he encontrado los componentes que se indican en declarations:

```
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    DishdetailComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HighlightDirective
  ],
```

Si estas empezando con angular te recomiendo que sigas el tutorial oficial de angular
https://angular.io/tutorial

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Luché durante dos días para entender el error. No sabia que esta fue un error tan estupido. Sin embargo ahora obtengo un error nuevo : `ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(1,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Component'.
src/app/app.module.ts(5,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Documents/Coursera/Angular/conFusion3/node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MaterialModule'.` y ademas no aparece nada sobre el localhost ...